# Uncaught TypeError: scrollIntoView is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, typeerror, js-scrollintoview

I can't figure out why, but `scrollIntoView()` function doesn't work. The browser displays an error: `Uncaught TypeError: element.scrollIntoView is not a function at ...`. The element `element` is defined and displayed in console. I haven't been able to find any answer in the Internet. Below is simplified code:

```
[...]
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        if (is_array($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $element) { ?>
                <tr data-someid="<?= $element->some_id ?>">
                    <th><?= $element->id ?></th>
                    <td><?= $element->name ?></td>
                    <td><?= $element->surname ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } 
        } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
[...]
<script>
    var element= document.querySelectorAll('[data-someid="' + someId + '"]');
    console.log(element); // displays the element well
    element.scrollIntoView();
</script>
[...]
```

Do somebody have any ideas why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a *list* of DOM elements. Right now you're trying to access a method `.scrollIntoView` on the returned `NodeList` which of course doesn't exist.

You probably meant to use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which returns a single element.

Comment: Thanks, Nik, it got rid of the error. But the function isn't still working. The screen doesn't scroll anywhere

Comment: Well that's another issue; Edit your question to include my recommendation and perhaps someone else can help. On 2nd thought, I'd suggest you create a brand new question.